# How to select from 3 tables in a series using Linq?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq, entity-framework

I have 3 tables:

Degree(Id int(PK), DegreeName string)

```
1   Bachelor
2   Master
3   PhD
```

Track(Id int(PK), DegreeId int(FK), TrackName string)

```
1   2   Engineer
2   1   Technician
3   1   Assistant
4   2   Physicist
5   3   Doctor
```

Group(Id int(PK), TrackId int(FK), GroupName string)

```
1   4   Group1
2   3   Group2
3   1   Group3
4   3   Group4
5   2   Group5
```

there is a one to many relation between Degree and Track, and another one to many relation between Track and Group.

I have this class:

```
Public class DegreeDetails
{
    public List<Track> TrackList { get; set; }
    public List<Group> GroupsList { get; set; }
}
```

to get all tracks these belong to bachelor degree, which are technician and assistant, I use this code:

In the controller I use this code:

```
DegreeDetails MyView = new DegreeDetails();
MyView.TrackList = entity.Track.Where(s => s.DegreeID == 1).ToList();
```

how to get a Group List of all groups these study tracks belong to bachelor degree, which should be Group2, Group4 and Group5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the best thing to do is to join these tables. You could create a view in your database, or you can join tables using Linq.

This should work:

```
MyView.GroupList = (from d in entity.Degree
                    join t in entity.Track on d.Id equals t.DegreeId
                    join g in entity.Group on t.Id equals g.TrackId
                    where d.Id == 1
                    select g).Distinct().ToList();
```

**UPDATE** If you want to use lambda exp, try this:

```
MyView.GroupList = entity.Degree.Where(d => d.Id == 1)
                    .Join(entity.Track, d => d.Id, t=> t.DegreeId, (d, t) => t)
                    .Join(entity.Group, t => t.Id, g => g.TrackId, (t, g) => g)
                    .Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Thank u very much. It works perfectly. Do u have any Idea about how to convert this joins to use lambda expression, as I've done in TrackList?? just to keep coding unification.

Comment: @Dr.MAF I update my answer, I didn't verify the code, but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You should join tracks with groups:

```
var groupList = entity.Track.Where(s=>s.DegreeID == 1).Join(entity.Group, t=>t.Id, g=>g.TrackId, (t,g)=>g).ToArray();
```

Comment: Your answer works in case of using type 'var'. I edited my question. Please, check it again to help me overcoming my problem. It gives me this error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Group[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Group>'